# How can I retrieve a 2D array by its header?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: screenshot of my google sheets]

What I am trying to accomplish here is to build a spreadsheet for meal planning.

On the left side, with the column header called dish ideas, I am logging all the individual ingredients of a recipe.

On the right side, with the drop-down menu E2, I want to be able to select the header (dish idea) and retrieve a 2D array of QTY, Unit, and Item with the matching header name.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter(B2:D, A2:A = E2)
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Marked as looks OK, but I think that we should already have questions that have answers with something like this.

Comment: As I mentioned, the flag as low-quality was done by the system. Not sure if you read the edit of my comment. Anyway, I will look to open a  Meta discussion in the near future, after the resultant community policy of the current featured meta-discussion is published.